# How to pass raw connection string

Tags: entity-framework-6

I saw a lot of similar questions but the answer is the same.

```cs
public class myContext(string connectionName) : base(connectionName)
{
}
```

The problem is all of their answers specify a connection NAME derived from their .config like:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionName" 
         connectionString="data source=server\database;initial catalog=catalog;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

What if I want to pass something like this

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=sampleDB;User Id=foo; Password=bar"
```

or something like

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=440;Database=mysqlDB;Uid=root; Pwd=root123;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c'tor of `DbContext` takes a string that is named `nameOrConnectionString`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Parameters:
>   nameOrConnectionString:
>   Either the database name or a connection string.

So you can pass both, a name to a connection string, or the direct connection string.

**Pass a name:**

To pass a name to `DbContext` (e.g. in your web.config), write something like:

```cs
new myContext("name=connectionName")
```

**Pass a connection string:**

To pass a literal connection string, write something like:

```cs
new myContext("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=sampleDB;User Id=foo; Password=bar")
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a half-second.

Comment: but how do I tell the constructor that it is a raw connection string and not a named one?

Comment: @anaval I've added examples on how I do it in my own projects.